# LaTeX and Table formatting

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Without specifying width for last column:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland,
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning.
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**I want to bold the line of the first row-column and last row-column.**
How to do this?

Comment: change `l` (which is a one line cell) to `p{3cm}` or whatever width you need.

Comment: How to manage the cell length?

Comment: pick it by hand or use a package such as tabularx, see any latex tutorial. (choosing it by hand is usually better unless you are automating thousands of tables from some database)

Comment: Take a look a t this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149810/troubles-with-column-width-in-the-tables-headings/149816?noredirect=1#comment341538_149816) I did few days ago. The answers can help you to improve the way you manage the cell width @ComplexGuy.

Comment: If I want to make bold 1st row+column  and  last row column then what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

Without specifying width for last column:

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| >{\bfseries}l | l | l | X |}\hline
    Day & \bfseries Min Temp & \bfseries Max Temp & \bfseries Summary \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland,
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning.
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]